# why does my regex return ''?

Tags: python, regex

when I run a regex searching for names on a string I get a list containing the names with extra `''` returned:

```
'Stephen Booth'

['Stephen', '', 'Booth', '']
```

this happens if I search using `r'\w*'` or `r'\S*'`

what are the extra `''`?

Comment: It is a basic problem in regex, `*` matches 0 or more occurrences, `+` matches one or more. Just use `\w+` or `\S+`.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Thank you.